# Disable Chrome autocomplete from using Google account's browser history

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm using Chrome (Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)) on my work laptop (MacOS Catalina 10.15.4), and would like it to separate it from my personal Google account. However, search keeps giving suggestion from my personal account history (from the clock icon), as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ppuy.png):

What I have done:

- Signed out from Chrome (Chrome is not using my Google account, and
  therefore sync is disabled)
- Allow use of Google services without
  signing in to Chrome Signed in to Google Drive and Mail to use their
  services
- Cleared all browser history and cache

When I signed out from Google Drive, the search bar stops giving suggestion from my personal account's search history. When I sign back in, it comes back. I believe the intended behaviour of the [screenshotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Tj9.png) option is not working, as Chrome still silently use data from my personal account when I signed in to Drive/Gmail.

What I don't want:

- Stop using autocomplete (therefore, disabling [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psCOm.png) option will not
  suit my use case)
- Stop recording browser history for my personal account, as I need it for my personal use (therefore, modifying account activity won't
  work either)
- Stop using Drive/Gmail on Chrome

Is it possible to isolate my work laptop's Chrome from the data from my Google account, if I am using other Google services on it? Or at least, to stop autocomplete from suggesting items from my personal browsing history?

Thank you.